# cursor not being compiled successfully in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have table city which has two columns city_id and city_name.

So,I declared plsql block to see the output of this table.Here,what I tried is:

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE 
    CURSOR CUR_NAME_LIST IS
    SELECT * FROM OT.CITY;

    V_NAME VARCHAR2(20);

BEGIN
    OPEN CUR_NAME_LIST;
    LOOP
    FETCH CUR_NAME_LIST INTO V_NAME;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_NAME.CITY_ID);
    EXIT WHEN CUR_NAME_LIST%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE CUR_NAME_LIST;

END;
/
```

When I compiled,then I got the error as:

```
ORA-06550: line 11, column 33:
PLS-00487: Invalid reference to variable 'V_NAME'
ORA-06550: line 11, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cursor returns two columns so in `INTO` clause there must be two variable or one variable of type that has two columns.

In your case, define one more variable for id and use it in `INTO` clause. Or use variable of type `city%rowtype` to handle all the data.

Something like following:

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE 
    CURSOR CUR_NAME_LIST IS
    SELECT * FROM OT.CITY;

    V_CITY CITY%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
    OPEN CUR_NAME_LIST;
    LOOP
    FETCH CUR_NAME_LIST INTO V_CITY;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_CITY.ID || ' - ' || V_CITY.NAME );
    EXIT WHEN CUR_NAME_LIST%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE CUR_NAME_LIST;

END;
/
```

-OR-

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE 
    CURSOR CUR_NAME_LIST IS
    SELECT ID, NAME FROM OT.CITY;

    V_NAME VARCHAR2(20);
    V_ID NUMBER;

BEGIN
    OPEN CUR_NAME_LIST;
    LOOP
    FETCH CUR_NAME_LIST INTO V_ID, V_NAME;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_ID || ' - ' || V_NAME );
    EXIT WHEN CUR_NAME_LIST%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE CUR_NAME_LIST;

END;
/
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Updated the answer with usage of rowtype also